# DQL Update Set ( Doctrine 1.2 )

Tags: set, dql, doctrine-1.2

i'm trying to update a row in a mysql db. I'm getting some problem and i'm new in doctrine (1.2 unfortunately) dql, i guess i`m getting an error because of the "sets" part, but i dont find the corret way to do it anywhere...

```
    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('OfferUser')
        ->set('price_alone', $price_alone)
        ->set('price_group', $price_group)
        ->set('comments', $comments)
        ->where('id=?', $id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the problem was the set... I had to put , '?' In the middle like this:

set('price_group', '?', $price_group)

Comment: I had the same Issue with

`$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->update('Notification ns')
                    ->set('ns.status',1)
                    ->set('ns.seenTime',$timestamp)
                    ->where("ns.notificationId = $notifictionId")
                    ->andwhere("ns.empNum = $userId");`
using 
`set('ns.seenTime','?',$timestamp)` fixed it

Comment: Described in the official doc in the 2nd example: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#update-queries